# Placing ORDER BY in the right place

Tags: oracle

**Should the ORDER BY been placed at the very bottom of the query? Under the FROM departments?**

[image]

Comment: The answer is found in the syntax diagram in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html)

Comment: Conceptually, it makes no sense to order only the first part of the query, as the final combined result can't possibly honour the requested ordering. You can check what happens using a range of RDBMS products at [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=b238fa0e5715d289c15d00d0c49232b5).

Answer (score 1):

An `ORDER BY` applies to the entire `UNION` result set. You cannot sort individual `SELECT` results within the `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it for better clarity.